# How to split up column name and find dictionary meaning with wordnet?

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following data I am trying to get the dictionary definition with, but it only works if it is a single word. How can I make it so that it works with more than one word?

Code:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

columns = ['Sector',
 'Community Name',
 'Date',
 'Community Center Point']

tmp = []

for x in columns:
    syns = (wordnet.synsets(x))
    tmp.append(syns[0].definition() if len(syns) > 0 else '')
```

Output:

```
pd.DataFrame(tmp).T

                        0    1                               2      3
a plane figure bounded by       the specified day of the month
```

column 1 and 3 are empty because 'Community Name' and 'Community Center Point' contains more than one word.

Desired output:

```
                          0                                             1                                         2                                                                   3
Sector: [a plane figure...]   Community: [definition], Name: [definition]    Date: [the specified day of the month]  Community: [definition], Center: [definition], Point: [definition]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

columns = ['Sector', 'Community Name', 'Date', 'Community Center Point']

col_defs = []
for item in columns:
    tmp = []
    for word in item.split():
        syns = (wordnet.synsets(word))
        tmp.append(word+': '+syns[0].definition() if len(syns) > 0 else None)
    col_defs.append(', '.join(tmp))

for x in col_defs:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
Sector: a plane figure bounded by two radii and the included arc of a circle
Community: a group of people living in a particular local area, Name: a language unit by which a person or thing is known
Date: the specified day of the month
Community: a group of people living in a particular local area, Center: an area that is approximately central within some larger region, Point: a geometric element that has position but no extension
```